# .after() with elements not working

Tags: jquery

I have a single div with two select boxes inside of it.  After choosing one item in the first select, AJAX fills in the appropriate items in the second select box.  Once an item is chosen in the second select box, I'd like a new div to be created, after the first, with some new select boxes based upon the values in the first div.

It seems that .after, .insertAfter, .append won't work if I am trying to add an actual HTML element (div, h2, etc.).  If I just add plaintext to the .after, it works just fine.

So if I add `$('#form_pt1').after("<div id='test'>Form Part 2</div>")` it will not fire but if I add only the text 'Form Part 2' it will add it after the first div but as text only, not as an element.

Am I missing something here? Does it have to do with DOM?  I've checked this behavior in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.  It just won't fire when adding a div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("select#signup_cust_type_select").change(function(){
            alert($("#signup_cust_type_select").attr("value"));
            var id = $("select#signup_cust_type_select option:selected").attr('value');
            var zip = $("input#hiddenzip").attr('value');
            $.post("http://someip/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/select_type.php", {zip:zip}, function(data){
                $("select#signup_utility_select").html(data);
                });
            });
            $("select#signup_utility_select").change(function(){
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input#submitbtn").click(function(){
                $('#form_pt1').after("<p></p><div id='test'>Form Part 2</div>");
            });
        });
    </script>`
```

and HTML is basically:

```
<div id="form_pt1">
    <form id="the_form">
        <select box 1>
        <select box 2>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="new_div_should_go_here"></div>
```

IT only works if I edit the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input#submitbtn").click(function(){
            $('#form_pt1').after("Form Part 2");
    });
});
```

By removing the HTML elements, it adds the words 'Form Part 2'.

Comment: A code sample is worth 1000 words :)

Comment: It works just fine here, and should work acc documentation. http://jsfiddle.net/kBVvp/. Can you provide a sample fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample fiddle that I think is doing what you describe in your question. Here it is:

```
<form id="form_pt1">
    <div id="container">
        <select id="one">
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
        </select>
        <select id="two">
            <option>c</option>
            <option>d</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then the jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#one').change(function () {
        $('<div class="extra"> extra content here </div>').insertAfter($(this));
    });
});
```

And [here's the link](http://jsfiddle.net/DLyHk/) to the jsfiddle.

Comment: This is the fiddle page I created:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/WRGav/3/).  This also works so I've come to the conclusion that something on the WordPress page is causing the failure here.  Thanks all...